# Mendelson's book, truth function of n argument

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic

How can you explain the highlighted sentence? I don't understand whether the statement letter are variables ranging over T or F, or the $x_i$ are the variables. Or if both why do we have two sets of variables ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A truth function of $n$ variables (arguments) is technically a function from $\{T,F\}^n$ to $\{T,F\}$. That is, it’s a function of the form $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, where the allowed inputs for $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are $T$ and $F$, and the output of the function is $T$ or $F$. The inputs are the truth values of the statement letters of interest, and the output is the truth value of some logical combination of them.

As an example, the truth function for the logical connective $\leftrightarrow$ (‘if and only if’) is a function of two variables defined as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
&f(T,T)=T\\
&f(T,F)=F\\
&f(F,T)=F\\
&f(F,F)=T\,.
\end{align*}$$

To find the truth value of an expression $A\leftrightarrow B$, for instance, we let $x$ be the truth value of $A$ and $y$ the truth value of $B$; then $f(x,y)$ is the truth value of $A\leftrightarrow B$.

The truth function for the connective $\neg$ (‘not’) is a function of one variable defined as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
&g(T)=F\\
&g(F)=T\,.
\end{align*}$$

With $x$ and $y$ as before, the truth value of $(\neg A)\leftrightarrow B$ is $f\big(g(x),y\big)$, because $g(x)$ is the truth value of $\neg A$.

Comment: I wanted to know, does a thing like $f(A,B,...,F)$ make any sense or not. Because the symbols $A,B,C,...,F$ seem like variables themselves, since they have no definite value, but  they range over T and F, like $x_i$

Comment: @Physor: No, $f(A,B,\ldots,F)$ does not make sense here, because, as you say, the arguments are not truth values. What you **can** do is define a truth value function $v:\{A,\ldots,F\}\to\{T,F\}$ that assigns to each of those statement letters a truth value, and then talk about $f\big(v(A),v(B),\ldots,v(F)\big)$.

Comment: could you check the highlighted sentence, do you find well written ? I don't know how to understand it.

Comment: @Physor: Yes: it says exactly what it was intended to say. It is written in a fairly formal [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) that is less common in textbooks than it used to be, but it’s perfectly standard English.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: @Physor: You’re welcome.

Comment: I have another question. cuold you check it please 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828364/mendelson-intro-to-math-log-lemma-2-29-d

Comment: @Physor: Looks like Mauro took care of it. (That’s a good thing, since I only have the first edition, which I used back in 1967!)